# Create my own cocoapods library in swift error: Use of unresolved identifier 'ABXXXView'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am following http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create guide to created my own swift library.

Briefly steps:

1. `pod lib create MyLibrary`
2. And the question with Yes,Swift etc. (Example project created)
3. Created my own class `ABXXXView` to replace the default in '`Pods/Development Pods/MyLibrary/pod/Classes/ReplaceMe.swift`'

Then i want to make an example in **Example for MyLibrary** in `ViewController.swift`, when i used the class ABXXXView under my own pods, i got the error as title described:

```
    import MyLibrary
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let vi = ABXXXView()
        self.view.addSubview(vi) 
    }
}
```

Which means can't find "ABXXXView", but i have `import MyLibrary`, any hint? Thanks!

**EDIT**:
If i recreated a project with **Objc** language, everything works fine.

Comment: Did you set up your podfile to use frameworks?

Comment: yes. It's default added: ```use_frameworks!```

Answer (score 2):

Add the scope of your class "ABXXXView" to public.

```
public class ABXXXView : UIView {

}
```

I hope it will solve your problem.